# Soma de valores de array multidimensional no PHP

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Estou construindo um carrinho de compras e estou utilizando sessions para salvar os produtos do carrinho. A estrutura do array que salva os itens é a seguinte:

```
$_SESSION['carrinho'][ID_DO_PRODUTO;TAMANHO_SE_HOUVER] => QUANTIDADE
```

Um exemplo de itens no carrinho de compras seria:

```
$_SESSION['carrinho']['156;GG'] => 1,
$_SESSION['carrinho']['876;PP'] => 9,
$_SESSION['carrinho']['65;'] => 5,
```

O último item da lista acima é tamanho único, enquanto os demais são GG e PP respectivamente.
No entanto preciso somar a quantidade de itens total no carrinho. Conheço o array_sum, porém os índices do array são dinâmicos. Já pensei em utilizar o um foreach, mas pra mim parece mais feio do que minha implementação gabiarra.

Comment: Olá amigo, não é uma resposta para sua dúvida, mas para Carrinhos de compras a melhor opção é sempre trabalhar com Cookies, transfira este armazenamento para o Cliente e remova-o do servidor. Você continua a trabalhar normalmente com Array. Abraços.

Comment: Entendo amigo, nesse caso só mudaria de SESSION para COOKIE. Vou ver essa mudança.

Comment: Não concordo totalmente com @MarceloBarbosa, os cookies devem ser usados se for o caso do Ecommerce não tiver sistema autenticação ("conta de usuário"), os dados dos cookies ficam disponíveis no cliente, o que aumenta as chances de modificarem os dados e assim "hackearem" o seu site. Já session está do lado do servidor, portanto só quem tiver acesso a pasta './tmp' poderá editar... [continua no proximo comentário]

Comment: [continuando]...a unica desvantagem é que se a pessoa fechar o navegador o session pode expirar, mas é possível contornar isto. *SE O SEU ECOMMERCE* tiver que cadastrar após fazer o primeiro carrinho, então o melhor é salvar em session e após autenticar ou criar uma conta, isto ser MOVIDO para uma base de dados.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Armazenar Código e quantidade em um Cookie permite alguém "Hackear"? No máximo, se tiver sorte, alterar os produtos do carrinho. Carrinho é apenas um container temporário para a finalização da compra, na qual será necessário um login e ai sim o armazenamento em BD. Sempre que possível remover coisas inúteis do servidor, faça, como por exemplo "Carrinho de Compras", não existe alguma necessidade de armazenar esta informação em "Server-side" levando em consideração que seja manualmente no cookie ou diretamente no site, o usuário tem autorização para alterar seu conteúdo.

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa se é temporário então use session, e sobre impedir que a sessão expire ao fechar o navegador é como eu disse, existe solução para contornar isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que um `foreach` seja a solução mais simples e limpa para o seu problema:

```
$totalItens = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $itemID => $itemQTD) {
  $totalItens += $itemQTD;
}

echo $totalItens . ' itens no carrinho';
```

O uso do `foreach` é perfeitamente aceitavel quando vai haver apenas leitura do array.

Answer (score 0):

Além do `foreach`, é possível usar uma *closure* (função anônima) para fazer a soma:

```
$contagemTotal = array_reduce($produtos['carrinho'], function($contagemTotal, $contagem) {
    return $contagemTotal += $contagem;
});
```